# Reg REST API for Solr restart operation

Tags: solr, solr8.4.1

I am in the process of creating an Web Application which will function like an Solr UI interface, there by allowing the User to execute Function commands / REST API to Solr by Web Application Widgets for an better User Interface feeling for Apache Solr. Can anyone share me the REST API details for an Solr Instance restart operation. Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
GPS.

Comment: Instance restart would be outside of what Solr can do; if you want to restart the Solr instance itself, there is nothing in Solr's API to make it do that. You'd usually use an API to the process manager you're using to run Solr instead in that case.

Comment: There is an option to Reload a core from the API (http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=name-of-core) but as Mats said, I don't think there is one to restart Solr.